# downloading a Korean file name - parsing error

Tags: java, android

Below is my url with song with file name.

```
/iStudioBm/sample/가로수%20그늘%20아래서면.wav
```

This is how the request is going and 404 is thrown.

```
iStudioBm/sample/%EA%B0%80%EB%A1%9C%EC%88%98%20%EA%B7%B8%EB%8A%98%20%EC%95%84%EB%9E%98%EC%84%9C%EB%A9%B4.wav
```

---

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request( Uri.parse(mFileAbsolutePath));//
```

above is the where I have to pass the Uri.

```
        request.setDescription(mFileName+" download");
        request.setTitle("Istudio...");
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

        // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + Constants.BASE_FILE_PATH , mFileName);


        // get download service and enqueue file
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

How can i fix this. I can use only Uri no URL is accepted.

Comment: Would be easier to help if you would provide the whole URL.

Comment: Its just my local host

Comment: post some code that you use

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
try {
            URI uri = new URI("http://yourdomain.com/iStudioBm/sample/가로수%20그늘%20아래서면.wav");
            Uri finalUri = Uri.parse(uri.toASCIIString());

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I cannot use URL I can only use URI. My calling library accepts only URI no URL is accepted.

Comment: Now try this way may helps you

Comment: Uri not URI sorry for my mistake

Comment: http://10.0.0.39:8080/iStudioBm/sample/%EC%82%AC%EB%9E%91%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0%20%EB%95%8C%EB%AC%B8%EC%97%90.wav - out put of new method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52374/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-user1871847)